# Output Javascript Array into DIV

Tags: javascript, regex, url, output, textarea

I have function, which shows / should output the urls (it should just list the urls) from the textarea. At the moment however it only shows me the last result / url. How can I output all the arrays / urls (maybe into a div).

My Code:

```
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>

<div id="converted_url"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#textarea").on("change keyup paste", function() {
    var text=document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
    var link = '<div><a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a></div>';
    document.getElementById("converted_url").innerHTML=link
    })
});
</script>
```

**Output At the Moment (With this code):**

[image: Output]

**Wished (Should be):**

[image]

I don't want to have append results, where results aren't updated the the textarea is changed. I.E: 
[image]

Comment: Your `.replace()` callback allways completely overwrites the `<div>` content.

Comment: But it isn't overwriting as much as i know. It's just outputting the last url...

Comment: Do you know how I can get all urls?

Comment: Clear out the `<div>` before calling `.replace()`, and instead of updating `.innerHTML` accumulate the URLs in a string. Then after `.replace()` set `.innerHTML` to the string.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it... Could you send me the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you update the result area, you are overwriting the previous results. You need to append to it.

FYI: The `input` event is a broad event that will fire whenever there is any kind of input to an element. You may find that it is simpler and more straight-forward than listening for multiple events. Also, since you are using JQuery, you might as well use it consistently to get all your DOM references.

```js
let result = $("#converted_url");

$("#textarea").on("input", function() {
    result.html(""); // Reset the output
    
    var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    $("#textarea").val().replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
      var link = '<div><a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a></div>';
     
      // Append the new information to the existing information
      result.append(link);
    });
});
```

```css
textarea { width:200px; height:50px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
(Just type anything in the box to trigger the event.)<br>
<textarea id="textarea">http://google.com blah blah http://facebook.com</textarea>

<div id="converted_url"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you fot the code. But  there's a problem... It will show duplicate the output and when I clear out the textarea the last result is shown...

Comment: @brox You just need to add a line that clears the output element. Answer updated to show this.

Comment: Perfect exactly what I looked for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Although I have a question. Can you detect if a url occurs more than one time and sum it up / unite it and show the url just once. I.e: TEXT: blah blah google.com blah blah blah google.com blah blah facebook.com OUTPUT: google.com, facebook.com

Comment: @brox Yes, but that is a separate question and I would advise you to post a new question that just asks about that. But, here's a hint. Use the string `.split()` method to split the string into an array using spaces as delimiters. Then use the Array `.filter()` method to filter out duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code for solving your problem.

Let me know if you have any question regarding code.

```js
var urlsContainer = $("#converted_url");
var urlsTextArea = $("#textarea");
$("#textarea").on("input", function () {
  var text = urlsTextArea.val();
  var urls = [];
  var raw_urls = text.split('\n');
  for (x = 0; x < raw_urls.length; x++) {
    if (isValidUrl(raw_urls[x]) && urls.indexOf(raw_urls[x]) < 0) {
      urls.push(raw_urls[x]);
    }
  }
  urlsUpdated(urls);
});
function urlsUpdated (urls) {
  urlsContainer.html('');
  for (x = 0; x < urls.length; x++) {
    urlsContainer.append('<div><a href="' + urls[x] + '">' + urls[x] + '</a></div>');
  }
}
function isValidUrl(str) {
  var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
  if(!regex.test(str)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<div id="converted_url"></div>
```

**Update**

Good that you have found the solution. I added an working example-screenshot of mine solution.

[example-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qyylb.png)

**Update 2.0**

```js
let result = $("#converted_url");

$("#textarea").on("input", function() {
    result.html(""); // Reset the output
    
    var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    var urls = [];
    $("#textarea").val().replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
      if (urls.indexOf(url) > -1) {
        return;  
      }
      urls.push(url);
    });
    for (x = 0; x < urls.length; x++) {
      var link = '<div><a href="' + urls[x] + '">' + urls[x] + '</a></div>';
      result.append(link)
    }
});
```

```css
textarea { width:200px; height:50px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
(Just type anything in the box to trigger the event.)<br>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>

<div id="converted_url"></div>
```

*Example Screenshot*

[image: screen-shot]

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and for the code. The code above already works perfectly. Although I have a question. Can you detect if a url occurs more than one time and sum it up / unite it and show the url just once. I.e: TEXT: blah blah http://www.google.com blah blah blah http://google.com blah blah http://www.facebook.com OUTPUT: http://www.google.com, http://www.facebook.com

Comment: I updated the answer. I didn't changed the code but added a screenshot to show working example of my solution for your problem.

Comment: My code identifies each URL by a line break in text-area. You have to define a separator. I used line break as separator, you can define yours. You can change separator by changing `\n` in the code to anything like `|` or `,` I used `\n` which is a line break.

Comment: I just found a problem with this code... I have now changed it to a regular space. But now the line break wont work... I have a very good code from above (Scott Marcus). The only thing with his code is that if you have duplicate urls it will list both. Would be great if you could look at his code. I will open a seperate question for this issue. Thank you very much for your time i appreciate it !

Comment: Check update 2.0. I updated Scott Marcus's code a little solving duplication issue.